# How to run a application always in front even it is minimised?Android

Tags: android, service, background, frontend

I want to create a application which should run always in front even it is minimised it should bring back to front while accessing other application my application should open

only access of one application on device..

I followed [this](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/activity/android-start-service-boot-example/) to create a Boot time app

Now I want to run the application as end less service which always run my app in front even other app is open or run in front

Can any one help me on this kind...

Comment: What have you done? Any approach?

Comment: There are no examples related to So I am checking with advertisement apps which rung on androidtv etc.. But I have Done till Boot only I need to Run app which will always bring my activity to front If any examples help me There is nothing related to this...

Comment: In Android N It's very difficult to read the information about other application is being opened or not.
In previous version you can check the running process(UID) of the app.

Comment: Ok for Previous version also no problem Can My Min level is 4.4 to 6.0.1